# Remain navtab in the center of page even when change screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make this navtabs center of the screen as browser window resize? I need these tabs in the center and remain in the center when I change the size of the browser window.

Can anyone help me to do that?

Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-4">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#admin_login_form"><strong>Admin</strong></a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#librarian_login_form"><strong>Librarian</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="admin_login_form" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adminUserName" placeholder="UserName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="adminPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg " id="admin-login">Log In</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="librarian_login_form" class="tab-pane fade">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="librarianEmail" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="librarianPassword" placeholder="Password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" id="librarian-login">Log In</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is "remand"? Are you sure you're using Bootstrap 4? The nav-tabs links don't have the correct nav-link class.

Comment: its work correctly but i want to make it in center even screen size change

Comment: But you're using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you.

## Bootstrap-3

```
.center {
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

## Bootstrap-4

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   // for vertical-center: align-items-center
   // for horizontal-center: justify-content-center
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```